# New LED ceiling light flashing/flickering

Tags: lighting, led, flashing

I’ve just replaced an old lighting fixture (halogen bulbs) with a new semi-flush LED fixture (https://www.johnlewis.com/john-lewis-finn-led-hoop-semi-flush-ceiling-light/p5111758).

When I go to switch it on, it flashes/flickers and never gets to solid. It’s an old house with old wiring.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it on any sort of timer, dimmer, or "smart" light switch?

Comment: No, just a regular 2-way wall switch.